# Where to use await keyword - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to wrap the WebApi calls from MVC app. So I created the below generic method,

```
public async Task<T> GetApi<T>(T model, string uri) where T : class
{
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAPIURL);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response =  httpClient.GetAsync(uri).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
            }
        }

        return default(T);

    }
```

Here, where to use the await keyword to make my method async?

Comment: Read the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) that what is there for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` should be used instead of `Task<T>.Result`, `Task.Wait`, and `Task.ContinueWith`:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
  httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAPIURL);
  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
  var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
  }
}

return default(T);
```